# Fake HTML URL address when mouse is over a form

Tags: forms, if-statement, header, href

let's say that I have the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off"><input name="checking2" type="submit" value="Name" class="ssd"></form>
```

When a user submits the form this PHP code takes place:

```
if(isset($_POST['checking2'])){
$xmla = new SimpleXMLElement('passwords/' . views . '.xml', 0, true);
$plus = $xmla->goodx;
$result = $plus + 1;
$xmla->goodx = $result;
$xmla->asXML('passwords/' . views . '.xml');
header( 'Location: http://google.com' ) ;
}
```

And the following CSS to design the form: code:

```
.ssd {
border: none;
background-color: transparent;
padding: 0;
cursor: pointer;
font-size:89%;
display:inline;
text-decoration: underline; 
color: #00c;  
}
```

Now, every time that the user clicks on the form he is being redirected in return to google. The PHP code is supposed to add +1 to a xml file's value(It works) every time that someone submits the form. My problem is, that whenever someone places his mouse over the form's value, the URL that he sees is the URL address of the current page he is currently on, Not the URL he will be actually redirected to - Google. I am trying to fake the URL address, so instead of seeing the current page URL address(which is action=""), he will see the URL address of google. And no, do not suggest to just place the URL address of google in "action=", because then the PHP data does not being updated properly for some reason whenever I do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case I got you right, you want to change the forms action property, don't you?

If so, use this little javascript code:

```
 <script>
function fake_action(){
    document.forms["myform"].action="http://example.com";
    document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
</script>
<form id="myform" action="http://google.com">
    <input type="text" placeholder="placehold.it"/>
    <input type="button" value="send" onclick="fake_action();"/>
</form>
```

Just a quick explenation: I have replaced the submit button with a standard button and specified the fake_action(); function as onclick event handler for it. The fake_action function just change the form's action and submit it afterwards. So you can do your stuff without any problem.

(You should just check for GET / POST Parameters at the page load and eventually send them on to the second page after you received them on the first one ;) )

Comment: It's not what I was trying to do. I updated my post to be much clearer.

Comment: Anyone else got an answer?

Comment: Give me a bit, I have been coding for 22 hours yesterday haven't slept much since then and am currently working on some SQL stuff for university atm. I will update my solution in about one or two hours!

edit: I have now checked your updated description again and it should actually still work with my code. If you use a button instead of a submitbutton, you can fetch the data in JavaScript, process it and then redirect the user to google.

Comment: But "action=" must stay blank as I already stated, because otherwise the PHP of the form doesn't take place properly. EDIT: instead of activating the JAVASCRIPT funcion on "onclick=", can I activate the PHP function? that way it will work.

Comment: you can not directly call a php function as Javascript is executed on the client side but you can call it via jquery (or ajax in general) and wait for the response (and handle the response)